# Display a formatted version of a returned query value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to figure out the best way to go about a problem I'm having with our Database. I don't have the option to go back and change the architecture, and so I am stuck trying to figure out a workaround.

```
Table 1: 
User => Column MailingCountry = Either (en-Country(en-US), Country (US), or Null)
Table 3: 
SMSCode => Column CountryCode = en-Country (en-US), Column SMSCode = Code (1 for US).
```

I'd like to know if there is a way that I could:

1. Get the User.MailingCountry and check if it is in the format of 'en-US', 'US' or 'NULL'
2. If it is in 'en-US' we are good, if it is in 'US', I'd like to replace it in the returned results to 'en-US', and if it is 'NULL', id like it to default to 'en-US'.
3. Inner JOIN with SMS.CountryCode where User.MailingCountry = SMS.CountryCode and then retrieve the SMSCode.

I guess the problem is, I am not sure how I can do something like

```
Select m.MailingCountry, a.SMSCode FROM User m-> 
IF (m.MailingCountry = 'US' or m.MailingCountry is null) Then m.MailingCountry = 'en-US'
Inner Join SMSCode a on a.CountryCode = m.MailingCountry
```

Comment: Do you mean there are only 3 possible value for `User.MailingCountry` : 'en-US', 'US' or 'NULL' ? And regardless of whichever value it is, you want to return as `en-US` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can go for below query:

```sql
SELECT SMS.SMSCode
FROM
(SELECT CASE WHEN MailingCountry like '%US%' OR MailingCountry IS NULL THEN 'en-US'
            ELSE MailingCountry END AS MailingCountry
FROM User) AS u
INNER JOIN SMSCode AS SMS
ON SMS.CountryCode = u.MailingCountry
```